# How can I set computer usage time limits?

Tags: multimedia, parental-controls

I've got an old computer that I put Ubuntu on for my kids (11, 9, and 7). They're always fighting for who can get on the computer and I'm sick of trying to figure out who has had enough time.

Anyway, they each have different accounts on the computer and I would like to find something similar to an Internet café type of solution that gives each user an allotted amount of time per day or week that they can be logged in. Once the time is used up, they're kicked off and can't log in again until their time is automatically reset.

An example of how I would like this to work would be: 
child 1 gets 120 minutes per week.

- Day 1: 30 min

  Day 2: 0 min

  Day 3: 30 min

  Day 4: 30 min

  Day 5: 30 min

  Day 6: Can't log in

  Day 7: Can't log in

  Day 8: 30 min (day one fell off the 7 day revolving time period).

  etc.

Is there anything like that available for Ubuntu?