# Gnome utility to limit computer use?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation

I used to use a utility in gnome2. I would set it for ever hour or so, lock the screen for ten minutes. It was great; it couldn't be turned off or disabled and really helped me break away from the computer sometimes.

But now, I totally forgot how to access it. It was something in the top panel I think...I remember it would show a little bar graph in the panel; when the bar graph filled up it would lock the display.

Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Thank you!

edit: found this post, listing gnome-nanny, timepkr, and timeoutd. But none of those are what I'm looking for...

[How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Workrave?

http://www.workrave.org/

Comment: Hey, thank you, that is on the right track.

It isn't that; the thing I was thinking of was somehow built into Gnome2.

Unfortunately, I can't get this one to 'make.' after ./configure. I wonder why?

 *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Thanks anyhow, I will keep trying to figure this out!

Comment: Hey! Found the answer. This is in MATE on 12.04, also same in Gnome2, not sure if functionality is retained in Gnome-Shell. System->Preferences->Keyboard, 'Typing Break' tab. Voila! It totally locks down the computer so it can't be used without a hard restart for the specified period. Just what I needed ;)