# How to restrict a user account to a specific time period

Tags: 12.04, accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time)

I'm using 12.04 and would like to make one user account open for use 24/7 and one account only available from 8:00am to 12:00am so when the user attempts to login after midnight , they are denied access .

Comment: You need to create a [time.conf](http://askubuntu.com/a/70277/3940) and add [pam_time.so to /etc/pam.d/lightdm](http://askubuntu.com/a/72907/3940) as shown in the two answers I linked to from the question above.

Comment: @Takkat, thanks a lot. I flagged this as a duplicate and am very excited to implement the answer you linked to. Thanks for taking the time.