# Set logon hours for user accounts

Tags: login, users, schedule

I want to stop a user account from logging in after a specified time. I know how to do this on Windows, but I can't seem to find an a way to do this on Linux.

Comment: Is this close to what you want? If so we'll convert it to an answer... http://serverfault.com/questions/139789/how-can-i-limit-the-login-times-in-linux-for-certain-users

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](http://askubuntu.com/q/68918)

Comment: Mordoc, that's pretty much what I needed.