# How to force logout after a time limit?

Tags: logout

I work in a library and I need to set a time limit for the user, like 20 minutes, and when the time is over the user is forced to logout. 
Is possible to do that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time (replace kids by users :D )