# Is there any child safety software for Ubuntu?

Tags: internet

I have a son, 13 years old, who needs his laptop for school for better writing, etc. But naturally he wants to play with it after working.

Are there any programs or packages for safety on the internet? A program limiting the time on the web and filtering the webpages would be great.

Comment: As for time restrictions also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time (the answers to the question linked to as dupe are quite out of date).

Answer (score 2):

Filtering webpages can be done with [dansguardian](http://dansguardian.org/).

Time limiters I don't know any. But there are browserplugins which can do this, for example [leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/) for firefox. If you limit access to other browsers on the computer it can be used.