# How to see computer activity

Tags: logs

I am very very new to Ubuntu. I wish to know how to see user logs in Ubuntu. I realized that our son has been using his computer on days he's not supposed to. Apparently, he configured the computer that user logs are deleted so I don't see user logs except on the day the computer is turned on. Is there a way to see computer activity and which dates and time? I will really appreciate your responses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time)

Comment: @Tim, this question is at no possibility of being a duplicate. Your referenced question asks about restriction, this one asks about ability to view logs for logged in time

Comment: @PauliusŠukys it's what they're asking for. If they child has deleted the logs they won't be able to get the data, so this is what they need.

Comment: Even so, this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: @PauliusŠukys The OP says their kid is using the computer at unauthorized times.  The logs are removed so they want to track time of use.  Short of some syslog fun, the duplicate of "How to restrict time" is the closest approximation to what is needed here for this situation.  This would therefore achieve the goal of controlling computing time.  As the goal is identical I think this could qualify as a dupe.

Comment: @ThomasW. so you strictly impose the contrary to the direct question which is - "Is there a way to see computer activity and which dates and time?"

Comment: @PauliusŠukys I never said that, but the original question remains unclear, we know not what they're referring to by 'activity' or 'logs'.

Comment: If you refer to user Internet histories as 'logs' that's one thing, but if you are referring to the system logs and such, then you need to give the kids a `non-sudo` account so they can't edit system logs.  We need a lot more information on what 'logs' you're referring to and how you're seeing their 'usage time' in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Inside of the window that opened click "computer" with the hard drive icon to the left of it. Open the folder named var, than open log, than double click auth.log, you will see a lot of information that you can ignore but focus on the date and times showing on the left hand side as you scroll down.