# Pre-scheduled daily lock-out periods

Tags: login, restricted-access, parental-controls

I'm looking for an automatic way to lock out our home computer during certain pre-scheduled times of the day.  Rather than rolling my own script for doing this, is there some off-the-shelf software for this use-case?

In case this matters, the solution need not be absolutely bullet-proof.  I just need to raise the "activation barrier" just high enough to discourage casual use of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can implement this through the standard Linux authentication system (called `pam` - Pluggable Authentication Modules). This (amongst other things) is responsible for checking if users can log in.

Within the pam system, there's a module called `pam_time`, which allows you to set restrictions for logins based on the time of day. This is controlled by the file `/etc/security/time.conf`.

Something like this could work:

```
login;tty*;!kjo;Wd1500-2000
```

- to prevent everyone except the `kjo` user from logging-in (ie, using the `login` service, on any `tty*` terminal) from 3pm to 8pm on weekdays. Be careful though, I haven't tested this!

There is quite a bit of documentation about the configuration format in the `/etc/security/time.conf` file, and check the `pam_time` and `time.conf` manual pages for more information:

```
man pam_time
man time.conf
```

Once you've configured time.conf to your liking, you'll need to uncomment the following line in your `/etc/pam.d/login.conf`:

```
account requisite pam_time.so
```

Answer (score 0):

One module would be `pam_time`.

Your question may be answered by [How do I restrict my kids computing time.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time)