# How do I restrict my kids' computing time (application based)?

Tags: software-recommendation, parental-controls

I came from this similar question: [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time)

But I want to define a weekly computing time (e.g. 3 hours) for a specific application and the days when it's allowed to use (e.g. saturday/sunday).

I basically want to allow the educational use of the pc any time and allow games only on weekends.

Comment: whats the 0perating System?

Comment: @PRATAP Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Beta)

Comment: Something I wrote which is similar: [How do I restrict my kids' computing time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time)

Answer (score 0):

There is **Little Brother** that I recommend.
https://github.com/marcus67/little_brother/blob/fb_configuration_gui/README.md

The installation is not difficult if you go through the readme page.